# Using Jupyter notebook server to execute Python code on the browser?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub, jupyter-lab

Is it possible to run a Jupyter notebook server and run Python code (not a script, dynamic code based on actions in a webpage)?

My idea is to run Jupyter notebook server on a localhost, and leverage the Python data science stack for the analysis part.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This sort of question is generally considered too broad for this board. That being said, I regularly test my selenium applications via jupyter to interactively drive my chrome browser through the necessary steps, so I don't see why you couldn't do similar.

Comment: I am looking at all the options before diving to the implementation, just wanted to know if anyone in the community had this sort of thing working. How do you test your selenium applications via jupyter? and what do you mean by interactively drive chrome browser ??

Comment: I set up the [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) package with the chrome webdriver to create a new browser session, then "drive" the browser by selecting and clicking elements, using functions like `driver.find_element_by_class_name(x).click()`